# Sinatra render a ruby file

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How to render a ruby file (which in my case returns a pdf document) for example:

```
 get "/pdf" do
  @locals = {some_locals_hash}
  headers({'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
    'Content-Disposition' => "attachment;filename=\"test.pdf\"",
    'Expires' => '0',
    'Pragma' => 'public'})
  ruby :test, :layout => false, :locals => @locals
 end
```

I know Tilt does not have ruby template. For now I put all content in a `*.haml` file like:

```
 -# PDF file description
 :ruby
   pdf = Prawn::Document.new(
     ... docs settings)
     ... docs content
   end
 = pdf.render()
```

and I render it with `haml :template ...etc...`

Truth is, I only need this for syntax highlighting, my editor does not properly highlight embedded ruby code in haml files :(. So if it's to complicated don't bother...

Comment: I don't quite get it, you are creating an PDF because your editor doesn't highlight ruby or render with haml because of that? And where is the problem - your editor still not highlighting or pdf not being sent to browser or browser not diplaying the pdf?

Comment: How I do now (rendering haml templates) works great, but when I edit those haml files, my editor does not properly highlight embedded ruby code. And I wish to render rb files and replace haml files with rb files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed with a Tilt template

```
module Tilt
  class RubyTemplate < Template
    def prepare
    end

    def evaluate(scope, locals, &block)
      super(scope, locals, &block)
    end

    def precompiled_template(locals)
      data.to_str
    end
  end
  register 'rb', RubyTemplate
end
```

and with a helper method

```
helpers do
  def ruby(*args) 
    render(:rb, *args) 
  end
end
```

I't sure this is the best way, but at least is working :)